# What are the querying capabilities and syntax for JSON query in an Azure workbook?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, json-query, azure-monitor-workbooks

In Azure workbook edit mode, I clicked `Add query` and set `Data source` to `JSON`.

I could not find any documentation what is the syntax I can use. I looked for it in the official doc articles like:
- [Workbooks how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-workbooks)
- [Workbooks for VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-workbooks)

I managed to get the query to display a set of rows once I wrote `{StackTrace}`, which was a reference to a variable containing `dynamic` json array from previous Kusto query. But I do not know what else I can do.

[image]

Comment: you don't know how to set parameter "StackTrace", which is getting from a query?

Comment: I know how to do this. My question is: is there is anything else I can do with the JSON query beyond just pasting a parameter value? It is called "JSON query", so I expect there should be some querying capabilities available. For example, I tried `{stackTrace}.rows[0]` but it didn't work.

Comment: technically, it isn't called json query, it's a json data source.  its a "query" that gets its data from static json (though that json content can also contain parameter markers, so it isn't *entirely* static).  I'm thinking about renaming the data source to "Static data" and having json just be one of the possible options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON source allows you to add static data to a workbook and visualize it like you would any other data source.

[Image of a workbook with JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHT5w.jpg)

It does not allow you to transform the data or query for parts of the data.

You can however reference the JSON data in another query control with a [Merge](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/DataSources/DataSources.md#merge-data-from-different-sources) source to bring together data from different sources.

Also, comprehensive workbook docs can be found at this [Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks#azure-monitor-workbooks)